# How can I automate inputting text into a prompt?

Tags: kali-linux, openvpn

I was trying to automate the launch of OpenVPN, by placing this code into a .sh file and then launching it.

```
openvpn --config vpnbook-us1-tcp443.ovpn
```

After executing this command, I am brought to a text prompt where I am supposed to input the username (vpnbook) and then the password. Is there a command that will allow me to automatically input these two sections of text so that I don't have to type them in every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file to hold your auth details, with the first line being that username and the second being your password.

You can then modify your .ovpn file, adding a line:
`auth-user-pass THATFILE`

That should automatically handle those details for you.